# SQL Error: Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, foreign-keys, entity-framework-core

I am using SQL and attempting to Add-Migration using Entity Framework Core. I am unsure how to resolve this. It is for associating a review system with the user and the product. This worked in SQLite. Now using SQL server. I have tried to provide everything while being brief. I can provide more if needed. Below is my code, can anyone please help?

> An error occurred while accessing the IWebHost on class 'Program'. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_ProductReviews_AspNetUsers_ReviewerId' on table 'ProductReviews' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>   Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

I have tried the commented out code.

```
            protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Entity<MemberReview>()
                .HasKey(k => new { k.RevieweeId, k.ReviewerId });

            builder.Entity<MemberReview>().
                HasOne(u => u.Reviewer)
                .WithMany(u => u.ReviewedMembers);
                // .HasForeignKey(u => u.ReviewerId)
                // .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

            builder.Entity<MemberReview>().
                HasOne(u => u.Reviewee)
                .WithMany(u => u.MemberReviews);
            // .HasForeignKey(u => u.RevieweeId)
            // .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

            builder.Entity<ProductReview>()
                .HasKey(k => new { k.ReviewerId, k.ReviewedProductId });

            builder.Entity<ProductReview>().
                HasOne(u => u.ReviewedProduct)
                .WithMany(u => u.ProductReviews);
                //.HasForeignKey(u => u.ReviewedProductId)
                //.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

            builder.Entity<ProductReview>().
                HasOne(u => u.Reviewer)
                .WithMany(u => u.ReviewedProducts);
                //.HasForeignKey(u => u.ReviewerId)
                //.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
        }

        public class ProductReview
    {
        public Product ReviewedProduct { get; set; }
        public User Reviewer { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int ReviewerId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(30)]
        public string ReviewerUserName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int ReviewedProductId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(35)]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(420)]
        public string Review { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(2)]
        public int Rating { get; set; }
    }

        public class User : IdentityUser<int>
    {
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(12)]
        public string UserType { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime DateOfEstablishment { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(75)]
        public string KnownAs { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastActive { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(420)]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
        // REVIEW THING
        public ICollection<MemberReview> MemberReviews { get; set; }
        public ICollection<MemberReview> ReviewedMembers { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ProductReview> ReviewedProducts { get; set; }
        // *****
    }

        public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(75)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(420)]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
        public User User { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        // REVIEW THINGS
        public ICollection<ProductReview> ProductReviews { get; set; }
        // *****
    }
```

Comment: You are trying to use multiple foreign keys on a table with cascading but SQL server doesn't allow multiple cascading operations. If you want to use cascading-like features on all foreign keys you need to disable cascade option on foreign keys and use triggers to achieve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Entity<MemberReview>()
        .HasKey(e => new { e.RevieweeId, e.ReviewerId });

    builder.Entity<ProductReview>()
        .HasKey(e => new { e.ReviewerId, e.ReviewedProductId });

    builder.Entity<MemberReview>()
        .HasOne<User>(e => e.Reviewer)
        .WithMany(e => e.MemberReviews)
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.ReviewerId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict); ////////
                                                  //
    builder.Entity<MemberReview>()                //
        .HasOne<User>(e => e.Reviewee)            /// => only one of these two can be cascade
        .WithMany(e => e.ReviewedMembers)         //
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.RevieweeId)         //
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict); ////////

    builder.Entity<ProductReview>()
        .HasOne<User>(e => e.Reviewer)
        .WithMany(e => e.ReviewedProducts)
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.ReviewerId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
}
```

You had not provided the `MemberReview` class so I created this:

```
public class MemberReview
{
    public User Reviewer { get; set; }
    public int ReviewerId { get; set; }

    public User Reviewee { get; set; }
    public int RevieweeId { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the result:

[image: DB Diagram]

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked! One thing I changed was to swap the FK's on the MemberReview. ReviewerId became RevieweeId and vice versa on the .HasForeignKey...